# how to get all events for a specific date in devexpress schedule

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, schedule

I'm using devexpress schedule in wpf, my application has a windows service in background that is trying to send some date over tcp/ip for all the appointments an rscurrying events.

My problem is that I do not know how to get all the normal an recurring events for the specified date.

Comment: nothing related to devexpress, but mentioned in the post title. You might expand a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If your datasource is List you could do the following:

```
List<T> appointments = ((List<T>)appointmentStorage.Appointments).FindAll(myObject => myObject.Date.Equals(myDate));
```